# Drupal Views Complex Grouped Filters

Tags: filter, view

I have a Math Expression ($field_a - $field_b) that I want to create an exposed grouped filter for (select-list) so that I can effectively filter out my results.

How can I set this up so that users will be give two options based on the values of two field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a custom field handler for this purpose.